# Next keys on the keyboard check

Tags: java, validation

Is any simple way to check if string contains any combination of the keys that appear on the keyboard next to each other (like "asdf", "qwerty","jkl")? I would like to validate input contains to avoid dummy text.

BRs

Paweł

Comment: You only want to check the keys on the left and right? What about keys above and below?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to check if a specific word matches with the characters in the keyboard in order

If thats is the case then you can do like below

```
public static void check(String test)
{
    String x="qwertyuiop";
    String y="asdfghjkl";
    String z="zxcvbnm";

    System.out.println(x.contains(test) || y.contains(test) || z.contains(test));
}
```

Comment: What if test is `Aqwe`. It will still fail the check.

Comment: @user3437460 A is in the second row in the keyboard and qwe is in the first row, so obviously it will fail as aqwe is not in order in keyboard

Comment: But shouldn't it pass the check because part of it contains "qwe"? For example "qwetyu" will fail the check as well.

Comment: unfortunatelly I didn`t found any library which will find dummy inputs like asd aaa asda ddd etc :(